# Compute standard deviation for every 5 numbers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, std, standard-deviation

I have an array of numbers shown below. However, I can only calculate the standard deviation of the whole array with only output 1 result as shown below:

Codes:

```
function standard_deviation_sample ($a)
{
  //variable and initializations
  $the_standard_deviation = 0.0;
  $the_variance = 0.0;
  $the_mean = 0.0;
  $the_array_sum = array_sum($a); //sum the elements
  $number_elements = count($a); //count the number of elements

  //calculate the mean
  $the_mean = $the_array_sum / $number_elements;

  //calculate the variance
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_elements; $i++)
    {
      //sum the array
      $the_variance = $the_variance + ($a[$i] - $the_mean) * ($a[$i] - $the_mean);
    }

  $the_variance = $the_variance / ($number_elements - 1.0);

  //calculate the standard deviation
  $the_standard_deviation = pow( $the_variance, 0.5);

  //return the variance
   return $the_standard_deviation;
}


$a = array(1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8,9,20,11,12,13,14,2,16,17,18,19,27);
$standard_deviation = standard_deviation_sample ($a);

echo "standard_deviation = $standard_deviation<br>";
```

Results:

```
standard_deviation = 7.10004
```

Does anyone know how to compute standard deviation for **every 5 numbers** instead? So that the output will be:

```
standard_deviation_1 = 3.11448
standard_deviation_2 = 5.70088
standard_deviation_3 = 4.82701
standard_deviation_4 = 4.39318
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `array_chunk();` It'll split your array up into smaller arrays of a given size, so your code would now be:

```
$a = array_chunk(array(1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8,9,20,11,12,13,14,2,16,17,18,19,27), 5);

foreach($a as $b){
  echo "standard_deviation: " . standard_deviation_sample($b);
}
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/array_chunk

If you require the number at the end of your `standard_deviation_1` output, you could change the loop to a `for()` loop like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++){
  echo "standard_deviation_" . ($i + 1) . " " . standard_deviation_sample($a[$i]);
}
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine, i'll delete my answer and upvote it

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk), but there's a few more things you can improve on the code itself:

```
function standard_deviation_sample(array $a)
{
  $the_mean = array_sum($a) / count($a);

  return sqrt(array_reduce($a, function($result, $item) use ($the_mean) {
    return $result + pow($item - $the_mean, 2);
  }, 0) / (count($a) - 1));
}
```

The function itself can be greatly reduced by only using variables where they're needed; secondly, calculating the squared standard deviation is a great example of something you can solve using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce); you start with the initial value of `0` and the inner function keeps adding the squared differences together.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8,9,20,11,12,13,14,2,16,17,18,19,27);

foreach (array_chunk($a, 5) as $k => $sample) {
  printf("standard_deviation_%d = %.5f<br>\n",
    $k + 1,
    standard_deviation_sample($sample));
}
```